# Maybe encoding is the bad guy?

Tags: php

It is a very simple dynamic page (php) with menu items which changes a GET id property which determins which text body to render.

As in hittinging the "Front Page" menu will render the site again with an internal id set to 1
where a few if-else determins what text to display.

Now, i was clicking around the links just to see that the text changed accordinglig but every 3-6 times i would hit a random menu item, some of the chars ( ø æ å) in the text on the entire page was replaced by (æ = Ã¦ ø = Ã¸ å = Ã¥)

The text is static on the site, it is not gotten from a database yet. This problem occers now and then and i cannot find a pattern in its occerens.

Anyone got a shoot at what might be wrong?

My sites meta tag is set to uft-8
(`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` so the encoding should be able to parse it)

The only thing i have been messing with on the site is .htaccess but as it stands now its empty.

Comment: Are you specifying a page encoding via the "Content-Type" header (if so, what is it), or letting the browser attempt to guess the encoding?

Comment: Best thing to do to avaid such encoding problems is to go for `htmlentities()` :D

Comment: @Tsadiq: No. UTF8 is clearly the better way.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your character encoding is set to UTF-8 both in the `http-equiv="Content-type"` meta tag and in the `Content-type` header sent by the server - usually browsers prefer the real header over the meta one.

To send the header from your PHP script, use `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Another way would be doing it in your htaccess file.

Comment: I got the meta set as default (forgot to add it in a code tag -.-) But how do you set this Content-type in the header sent by the server?

Comment: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: now for some more noobness, sorry, but where exactly do i add this piece of code?

Comment: The best place is right after the `<?php` line as it needs to be sent before any output has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the HTML encoding:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
...
```

Also, your pages should be encoded in UTF-8. Almost any editor offer choice of encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of your files and the encoding declared in the HTTP headers and / or `<head>`. They must match in order to have the good character shown in the browser.

If you're under linux, you can change the encoding of a file with [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html).

If you still have problems, theres mainly two way to resolve them :

1. Using [html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp), but it can be very tedious.
2. Declare your page as UTF-8, and use [utf8-encode](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

To declare your page as encoded with UTF-8, add the following to your `<head>` :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your html in your head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was a browser problem after all. . . When i was using firefox it keept screwing up but when i switched to IE it was all good. . . There does not seem to be any problem for other people so guessing i got some crap on my puter i need to weed out.

But thanks alot for your awnsers!